# Chrome & Captive Portals: Search and URL vs IP

Tags: google-chrome, ip, captive-portal

When I am somewhere that uses a captive portal (library, airport) Chrome will typically not load the login/"agree" page. If I type in a website ("twitter.com") or a search ("cool rats") I just get "This webpage is not available" etc.

Firefox will do it, so even if I was using Chrome my workaround was to pop open Firefox, type anything into the address bar, get redirected to the page where I agree to the terms or whatever, and then just close it and go back to using Chrome.

I discovered by accident a while back that while Chrome won't redirect to the captive portal login from a search or a provided URL, it will successfully kick me over to the captive portal page if I type in something in the format of an ip address. (It could be anything; 10.10.10.10 does the trick.)

So my question is: why is that?

Comment: It might be that the captive has difficulties intercepting the request; one thing you should try is load a non https website.

Comment: Have you checked your browsers' proxy settings ? It sounds a bit like you are sending requests to any named domains in Chrome towards a proxy (and preventing a redirect from occuring), while allowing names which are actually IP@ to go direct, and thus trigger a redirect. Firefox allows you to control proxy settings differently from Chrome, which could explain the difference in behaviour you are seeing.

Comment: http://neverssl.com/

Comment: I haven't changed the proxy settings in either browser but I will check them to see if they are configured differently as default. The https/http angle seems like it could be what's going on. I will test with neverssl next time I'm somewhere with a captive portal. Thanks to all for helping me satisfy my curiosity!